# Custom Bootstrap Icon for each group LazyLoading - FancyTree

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fancytree

I am lazy loading a FancyTree.

I have groups and then Sub Groups. I want a different Icon for each sub group.

[image]

This is the jQuery code to Load the Tree:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var glyph_opts = {
            map: {
                doc: "glyphicon glyphicon-file",
                docOpen: "glyphicon glyphicon-file",
                checkbox: "glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked",
                checkboxSelected: "glyphicon glyphicon-check",
                checkboxUnknown: "glyphicon glyphicon-share",
                dragHelper: "glyphicon glyphicon-play",
                dropMarker: "glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right",
                error: "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign",
                expanderClosed: "glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign",
                expanderLazy: "glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign",
                expanderOpen: "glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign",
                folder: "glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close",
                folderOpen: "glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open",
                loading: "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"
            }
        };

        $("#tree").fancytree({
            source: $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CompaniesTree", "Dashboard")',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json"
            }),
            extensions: ["glyph"],
            glyph: glyph_opts,
            lazyLoad: function (event, data) {
                var model = {
                    key: data.node.key,
                    data: data.node.data
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ChildItems", "Dashboard")',
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(model),
                    success: function (response) {
                          data.result = response;
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Just in case you need to know the Server side code: I am returning a `List<TreeModel>` from my controller, I need to add another Property to this Response which should change the Icon,

```
public class TreeModel
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public bool lazy { get; set; }
    public bool folder { get; set; }
    public TreeItem data { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply edit the class names that are used for the glyph icons.

```
map: {
    doc: "glyphicon glyphicon-file",
    docOpen: "glyphicon glyphicon-file",
    ...
```

Your example uses the [Bootstrap Glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons), but also [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) and others are available.

**Edit 2015-11-21:** Note that starting with Fancytree 2.14 `iconClass` was replaced by `icon`.

Use the `iconClass` callback to define per-node custom icons
(**Note:** the following sample uses Fancytree v2.11.1 or later):

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
  ...
  iconClass: function(event, data){
    if( data.node.isFolder() ) {
      return "glyphicon glyphicon-book";
    }
  },
```

Another approach is to override the icon class directly with the node's `iconclass` property:

```
[
  {"title": "Node 1", "key": "1", "iconclass": "glyphicon glyphicon-book" },
  ...
```

Comment: But that changes the icon for the entire tree. I need different icon for each level.

Comment: I updated the sample accordingly. Note that the iconClass callback receives a `node` argument until v2.11.0. This was changed with v2.11.1 as shown in the sample above.